# Form Collection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an html begin form in mvc

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Reports",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-inline"  }))
{ 
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value" name="SearchValue">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm second-value" placeholder="Value" style="display:none;" name="SearchValue1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-Add">+</button>

    </div>
    <div id="othersearch"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

I want to post this form item in one controller

```
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
{
    string searchvalue = collection.Get("SearchValue");
    return View();
}
```

my problem is that some times second text box is not visible.. that time i dont want to collect the values.And when i press button add generate the same type of input field in the form with same name (i can add many input box). Then how can i collect all these in my controller . please help me..

Answer (score 5):

You can have all the text boxes with same name "SeachValue" in your case.

> `string searchvalue = collection.Get("SearchValue");`

This will return all text box values as comma saperated string which you can split and use further.

Check out the screen shot
[image]

the html

[image]

and the results

[image]

Comment: its in the case of same row, after pressing button + <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value" name="SearchValue">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm second-value" placeholder="Value" style="display:none;" name="SearchValue"> again generated total i have to collect 4 textbox value

Comment: No matter how much text boxes are there if they have save "name" they will be posted to action under save form collection key.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of all textboxes having same name using following code:

```
    var results = ((String[])formcollection.GetValue("mytxt").RawValue).ToList();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                //string name = item;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you add a element dynamically make sure you also set it a name. so when you add a new input element it must be

```
 <input type="text" name="NewTextBox" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value" name="searchvalue">
```

So like this no matter how many text boxes you add, All will have same name. Once you post the form. In your controller do this.

```
[HTTPPOST]
public ActionResult Search(MyModel newModel,string[] NewTextBox)
{
 // here as you had dynamic textbox with name = NewTextBox you 
 //will get all its value binded to the above string[]

}
```

OR

You can retrive them using `Request.form["NewTextBox"]` as

```
[HTTPPOST]
public ActionResult Search(MyModel newModel) 
{ 
 var values = Request.Form[NewTextBox];    
}
```

But I would recommend you the first approach where you use the `MVC Model Binder` to take care of all the things. You will just have array of values to play with.

**NOTE:** Always make sure you get the names right, and use the name right while playing with MVC. As all the binding depends on the naming itself.