# Form Collection issue from dynamically added input fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an input box in my html begin form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Reports",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"))
 {
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value" name="searchvalue">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-Add">+</button>
   <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
  }
```

when I press on the add button my form become:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Reports",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"))
 {
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value" name="searchvalue">
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value" name="searchvalue">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-Add">+</button>
   <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
  }
```

how can I collect this form values in my controller or is there any jquery method for posting this to my controller?Please help me.

Comment: How many times you are asking this question ... 1 hour ago you asked same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746218/form-collection-issue

Comment: i cant find the answer yet..

Answer (score 3):

When ever you add a  element dynamically make sure you also set it a name. so when you add a new input element it must be

```
 <input type="text" name="NewTextBox" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value" name="searchvalue">
```

So like this no matter how many text boxes you add, All will have same name. Once you post the form. In your controller do this.

```
[HTTPPOST]
public ActionResult Search(MyModel newModel,string[] NewTextBox)
{
 // here as you had dynamic textbox with name = NewTextBox you 
 //will get all its value binded to the above string[]

}
```

OR

You can retrive them using `Request.form["NewTextBox"]` as

```
 [HTTPPOST]
    public ActionResult Search(MyModel newModel)
    {
     var values = Request.Form[NewTextBox];

    }
```

But I would recommend you the first approach where you use the `MVC Model Binder` to take care of all the things. You will just have array of values to play with.

**NOTE:** Always make sure you get the names right, and use the name right while playing with MVC. As all the binding depends on the naming itself.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use FormCollection to get textbox values. like below:

```
  public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
   {
    //string searchvalue = collection.Get("SearchValue");
    var results = ((String[])formcollection.GetValue("SearchValue").RawValue).ToList();
    return View();
  }
```

Comment: Why using Form collection when MVC provides us the model binding feature

Answer (score 0):

If you add extra fields that aren't in your model, you can use FormCollection as your model type, or look in the HttpContext.Request.Form for your values.

As you are adding the name searchvalue twice, you will probably see it in the FormCollection as [0].searchvalue and [1].searchvalue

you will need to iterate over these to get the values out of them.

Si